# edit json in visual studio code editor

Tags: json, editor

when trying to edit an existing [json file](https://github.com/pmpkk/openhab-habpanel-theme-matrix/blob/master/Ground%20Floor%20Widget.widget.json) in visual studio code editor (or notepad++), there is no formatting whatsoever. Looks as if line breaks are missing. Reformatting function does not work, nor do any plugins help. What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mohsen1.prettify-json?

Comment: Notepad++ can import user-defined language.

Comment: just tried prettify json, did not work. Does it work for you (see link above in json file)?

Answer (score 0):

Add extension json as shown in the image attached. Right click on the code and click "Format Document".[image]